# Remove one to one relationship in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm using Laravel 5.2  and I have created a one to one relation as follows.

```
 $driver    = Driver::find($driver->id);
 $vehicle = Vehicle::find($vehicleId);
 $vehicle->driver()->associate($driver);
 $vehicle->save();
```

This works perfectly. In some scenarios I need to break this relationship by removing the particular driver from the vehicle.

```
$driver    = Driver::find($driver->id);
$vehicle = Vehicle::find($vehicleId);
$vehicle->driver_id->NULL;
$vehicle->save();
```

But this doesn't work. I have tried some other approaches.

```
$vehicle->driver()->delete();

$vehicle->driver()->dissociate();
```

Following are the two models.

```
class Driver extends Model
{
    public function vehicle()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Vehicle::class);
    }
}

class Vehicle extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'vehicle_number';
    public $incrementing = false;

    public function driver()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Driver::class);
    }
}
```

Nothing is working in my case. Could anyone please give a hint, what's wrong in there.

Comment: $vehicle->driver()->delete(); will delete the driver not the relation

Comment: Provide code for both models

Comment: @KuKeC Added to the question.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need:

```
$vehicle->driver_id = NULL;
$vehicle->save();
```

Comment: @Shashika, In your answer - `$vehicle->driver_id->NULL;`. If it's real case, you wrong tried.

Comment: If you var_dump the return from the save call does it return true or false? Also @Shashika, from your question your Vehicle model doesn't have an id column does it? You appeared to have set the primary key to be vehicle_number.

Comment: Late answer but these comments are wrong.  What you have here is correct, and it's fine if driver_id is not fillable.  The reason it doesn't appear to work is because $vehicle already has its relationship model loaded and updating the raw attribute won't change that until that relationship is reloaded.  Try $vehicle = $vehicle->fresh(); after this.

Answer (score 2):

First of all i think you did wrong with inserting data

```
$driver  = Driver::find($driver->id);
$vehicle = Vehicle::find($vehicleId);
$vehicle->driver()->associate($vehicle);
$vehicle->save();
```

should be

```
$driver  = Driver::find($driver->id);
$vehicle = Vehicle::find($vehicleId);
$vehicle->driver()->associate($driver);
$vehicle->save();
```

Your models should be like below

```
class Driver extends Model
{
    public function vehicle()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Vehicle::class);
    }
}

class Vehicle extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'vehicle_number';
    public $incrementing = false;

    public function driver()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Driver::class);
    }
}
```

Try it and let me know if it helped you

Comment: Sorry it's my fault, when I wrote the question. My relatioship addition works fine.

Comment: @Shashika I also edited relationships in your models. Do this updates and let me know if you got still errors

Comment: This doesn't work. I need the relationship direction on that way.

Answer (score 0):

If You are using foreign key between vehicle and driver ,you just need to delete the child table entry or make reference Null.Is driver_id nullable.
In migration try this, 
$table->integer('driver_id ')->unsigned()->nullable()->default(null);
Hope this solves your issue.

Comment: $table->integer('driver_id')->unsigned()->nullable(); This is what I have in my migration

Answer (score 0):

To remove a parent model from a child model, you may use the `dissociate` method. This method will set the relationship's foreign key to null:

```
$vehicle->driver()->dissociate();
$vehicle->save();
```